# Identify the branch or trunk you are connected in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I couldn't find a way in IntelliJ to inform me to which branch or trunk repository of SubVersion,SVN I am connected to. 
I can change to different branches and/tags, but I never know which branch I am currently working with. In Eclipse, it is clearly identified along with the name of the project, but in IntelliJ, such is not displayed. Does any one know?
Current version: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.14

Answer (score 0):

You can see the URL used by the working copy at the moment in the Subversion Working Copies tab of the Version Control tool window.

It is not currently shown in the Project view or other locations.
Please vote for the following requests:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76042 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63893